# gcloud app deploy fails: "Cloud build did not succeed within 10m"

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-app-engine-python

I can't deploy a simple Flask/MySQL application on the Python standard environment; it times out.

`ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Cloud build did not succeed within 10m.`

In the logs it says this:

```
Step #7 - "exporter": Layer 'google.python.appengine:config' SHA: sha256:c7053ac3e...
TIMEOUT
ERROR: context deadline exceeded
```

This is app.yaml (appropriately censored):

```
runtime: python37

instance_class: F2

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /.*
  script: auto

env_variables:
  GAE_USE_SOCKETS_HTTPLIB: True
  DB_USER: XXXX
  DB_PASS: XXXX
  DB_NAME: XXXXXXXX
  CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME:XXXXXXXXXXX:us-west3:XXXXXXXXXXX
```

This is requirements.txt:

```
numpy==1.19.0
Flask==1.1.2
googleads>=24.0.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.17
PyMySQL==0.9.3
google-search-results==1.8.3
```

I've tried all kinds of things but nothing works. This used to run with no problems; we haven't changed anything. It's basically a Hello World Flask app.

Comment: can you try deploying using gcloud build following the documentation:https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-appengine#configuring_the_deployment. Where you can specify the timeout options upto 30 minutes.

Comment: I realized it was bundling and uploading a large temporary CSV file that I didn't realize was in the root folder. At the default warning level, the log reported it was bundling 30 files instead of 29, but didn't list them.

Comment: Glad, You resolved it!